# ActionScript 3 IDE which provides tools on Graphical Interface as well as Code

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, ide

This is my first post on Stack Overflow.

Are there any IDE's for ActionScript 3 which can provide the following:
-Graphical Interface for drawing
-Writing code with good debugging, dynamic feedback, refactoring etc

I have recently rekindled programming flash games in ActionScript 3 and am using Flash CS3 
as it provides means of drawing my graphical objects and writing the code.

I have noticed that:
1. Debugging is not particualr great 
2. No dynamic feedback whilst programming (suggestion or auto populate)
3. No refactoring etc

I have looked into other IDEs such as Flex Builder and even looked at plugins for my favorite 
IDE's such as Eclipse and IntilliJ but have not found my answer. They tend to talk heavuly about
how they provide good coding tools but not much, if any, tools on the graphical side of things.
It would also be ideal for me if what ever IDE I use I am still able to migrate the entire project
so that it can still be opened usign CS3. Additionally, I am a Windows user.

At the moment I am contemplating drawing my sprites in CS3 and doing the code in another but
surely there must be an easier, perhaps more sensable approach?

Many thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no IDE like that, and given the decreasing popularity of Flash it's unlikely that something like that will ever be  developed.

The coding environment has improved quite a bit in newer versions of Flash Pro, but it still doesn't approach anything like Flash Builder or FlashDevelop. It's not uncommon for people to create graphics in Flash Pro and do coding in another editor.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy. FlashDevelop for code. Flash IDE for graphics. You may want to graduate to CS5.5 or CS6 (if you can find a copy)if you want to go mobile. Otherwise CC.

Comment: Perfect. That should work for me. Many thanks for the response.